# Write a function to take 8 bits from an array and turn it into Decimal

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I'm trying to write a function that takes 8 bits from an array that is 6x24 (just consider it taking a byte 1 bit at a time) and convert it to a decimal integer. Meaning there should be 18 numbers in total. Here is my code

```
int bitArray[6][24]; //the Array of bits, can only be a 1 or 0
int ex=0; //ex keeps track of the current exponent to use to calculate the decimal value of a binary digit
int decArray[18]; //array to store decimals
int byteToDecimal(int pos, int row) //takes two variables so you can give it an array column and row
{
  numholder=0; //Temporary number for calculations

  for(int x=pos; x<pos+8;x++) //pos is used to adjust where we start and stop looking at 1's and 0's in a row
  {
    if(bitArray[row][x] != 0)//if the row and column is a 1
    {
      numholder += pow(2, 7-ex);//2^(7-ex), meaning the first bit is worth 2^7, and the last is 2^0      
    }
    ex++;
  }
  ex=0;
  return numholder;
}
```

Then you can call the function like so

```
decArray[0]=byteToDecimal(0,0);
decArray[1]=byteToDecimal(8,0);
decArray[2]=byteToDecimal(16,0);
decArray[3]=byteToDecimal(0,1);
decArray[4]=byteToDecimal(8,1);
decArray[5]=byteToDecimal(16,1);
```

ect. When I place a single 1 into bitArray[0][0], calling the function gives me the number 127, when it should be 128.

Comment: How exactly do you place a single `1` into `bitArray[0][0]`?, For me [everything works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f44722462ee1618a).

Comment: This is actually Arduino C if that makes much of a difference

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `bitArray` (or at least the bytes involved) is not filled with zeros. The reason for that may vary. Most likely you have some leftover from previous operations with it. The second (insane) reason is that maybe Arduino C compiler doesn't initialize static objects with zeros (I've hever had experience with Arduino so I can't tell for sure).

In any case, try to call `memset(bitArray, 0, sizeof(bitArray))` before you perform other operations with it.

Here is a [demo written in plain C](http://ideone.com/ppDXIq), demonstrating that normally your code should work fine.